# Spring Boot: Custome @Query with 2 consecutive brackets cause that one pair is ignored

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my JpaRepository I have following @Query:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Msg m WHERE ((m.from = ?1 AND m.to = ?2) OR (m.from = ?2 AND m.to = ?1))  AND m.time = ?3")
Msg find(String firstId, String secondId, long lastAccess);
```

however in log console is this query logged without the upper brackets and it seems that is executed that way:

```
SELECT m FROM Msg m WHERE (m.from = ?1 AND m.to = ?2) OR (m.from = ?2 AND m.to = ?1)  AND m.time = ?3
```

So how to properly add multiple consecutive brackets?

---

I use:

Derby

Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE

Comment: This could be a driver related issue specific to one of the vendors (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...). On HSQLDB I get the following: `(msg0_.from_id=? and msg0_.to_id=? or msg0_.from_id=? and msg0_.to_id=?) and msg0_.time_epoch=?`. It did remove the inner brackets, but that's correct since `AND` has precedence over `OR`. What database do you use? Also, can you show us the native query that is generated?

Answer (score 2):

I did some small investigation using Spring Boot **1.4.3-RELEASE** and **1.5.4-RELEASE** with two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have mimic your JpaRespository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE ((p.firstName = :firstName AND p.lastName = :lastName) OR (p.firstName = :lastName AND p.lastName = :firstName)) AND p.age = :age")
    Person findWithCustomQuery(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("age") Integer age);
}
```

Here is what `Person` class look like:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Integer age;
}
```

> Here is full source code: https://github.com/wololock/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/45629734

The SQL query I see that is executed is following:

```
select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.age as age2_0_, person0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, person0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_ from person person0_ where (person0_.first_name=? and person0_.last_name=? or person0_.first_name=? and person0_.last_name=?) and person0_.age=?
```

As you can see brackets where simplified to

```
(person0_.first_name=? and person0_.last_name=? or person0_.first_name=? and person0_.last_name=?)
```

but it is still correct since `and` operator has higher priority than `or` operator.

#### More information needed

I'm eager to help you finding solution to your problem, but I will need more information, e.g.

- what database do you use (I used H2 in this example and it's pretty obvious that different SQL dialect may generate different query)
- what version of Spring Boot do you use?
- what version of Spring Data do you use?